# NopCommerce - using metatag noindex on specific page and language

Tags: nopcommerce, metatag, noindex

I have a site that uses 3 languages. The thing is only one of those languages has a specific page. (the client wants each language to be used for each country that he sells to)

I could create a metatag in the header that would ignore the full page, but that would disable indexing that page in all languages.

Is there a way to disable indexing in a page only in specific languages? (using the WorkContext.WorkingLanguage.Id, i.e.)

Thank you.

TZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a HTML helper method that resolves the `IWorkContext` and checks the language locale for your languages to ignore, then returns a string with the noindex meta tag. Then, call that in your `/Shared/_Root.Head.cshtml` view